# should i tag my pictures or my albums

Tags: photos, tags

i am taking pictures of my daughter growing up.  i want to use tagging to get different views on her growing up but i am not sure if i should have tags at the picture or album level.

at this point, i have about 200 albums and about 9000 pictures.

One idea is to get rid of albums and just have tags but i do see the value of albums because there are specific occasions with dates that are a meaningful way to keep track.

any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds great for discussion, not so well for a concrete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should tag both. On average, you have 45 pictures per album.

I'm unsure as to how you decided to structure your albums, but in any case, 45 pictures means you have a wealth of information on each album which could need some tagging (and there's nothing wrong with having more than one picture with the same tags). Similarly 200 albums is an impressive number and clearly indicates you have some purpose for them. So, tagging these seems only natural.

One thought however you should have present... you should always consider your unit of information as your priority target for tagging. On this case (and pretty much on the case of computers), this is the file. So, the question to tag or not files should never be posed. Instead it's only the albums that may bring the doubt. With that number however, I do suggest you tag them in case you want to do an album search.